# Godot: exported boolean variable is always false

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a problem with an exported set of boolean variables, flags to enable an Area2D feature:

```
tool

extends Area2D

signal direction_changed

export(bool) var allow_right
export(bool) var allow_left
export(bool) var allow_up
export(bool) var allow_down

var controlled_component = null


var directions: PoolVector2Array
var direction: Vector2

func _init():
    init_directions()
   
    

func init_directions():
    print_debug(allow_down, allow_left, allow_right, allow_up)
    directions = []
    if(allow_right):
        directions.append(Vector2(1,0))
    if(allow_down):
        directions.append(Vector2(0,1))
    if(allow_left):
        directions.append(Vector2(-1,0))
    if(allow_up):
        directions.append(Vector2(0,-1))
```

and this results in showing the flags in my Scene inspector:

[image: Scene inspector]

what I don't get is why if I flag a couple of them like this:

[image: Flagged variables]

why the `print_debug` statement results in this:

`FalseFalseFalseFalse`

Shouldn't two of the bool variables be set to `True`?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a tool script, which runs inside the IDE. Therefore the "_init()" function (where you call "init_directions()" with print_debug) is called when you open a scene with this script for the first time. When you make a change in the inspector, the change will be applied if you save, close the scene and open it again.

Comment: Thanks! It was my fault, I should have used the _ready() method, not the _init() one